How to play audio (mp3) in Compose Multiplatform with Kotlin/Wasm target?
I’m developing a Compose Multiplatform application, and I’m targeting Kotlin/Wasm for the web. I need to play audio (mp3) files within my app, but I’m not sure how to achieve this using Compose Multiplatform and Kotlin/Wasm.
What is the easiest way to do this?
Tried two libraries, without success:

KorGE
AstroPlayer


There are several ways to play mp3 audio file in kotlin/js or kotlin/wasm.
MediaPlayer-KMP checkout this library. with the help of this library, you can play videos, youtube videos & audios as well on Android, iOS, Web and Desktop.
